# Where do we put code that was in -dealloc when converting to ARC?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting

I have a class with this method call within dealloc:

```
- (void)dealloc {

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Where would I remove myself from the notification center once I convert the class to ARC? Should it go within viewDidUnload? The notification is used to listen for events that come from a modal view controller, so I cannot put this code into viewWillDisappear.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `dealloc` stays in ARC, it's just that you shouldn't be calling `[super dealloc]` any longer: the compiler inserts the code for you. And of course all the calls to `release` cannot be made in `dealloc` (or anywhere else).

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
    // [super dealloc]; <<== Compiler inserts this for you
}
```